# How can I replace a certain row in a dataframe with multiple rows that i have stored, using a particular column to match?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working with the following pandas dataframe:

```
  time            market_state 
 5:00:00              open  
 6:00:00           continuous
 7:30:00           continuous
 9:12:00           unscheduled
 10:02:02          intraday 
 10:05:03          intraday 
 11:00:33          closed
```

My python code removes all rows that have consecutive `market_state`s, like `intraday` and `continuous` in the above example.

So i want to store the two rows with market_state `intraday`, and this is what I use:

```
store_intraday_market_state = df.loc[df['market_state'] == 'intraday']
```

So `store_intraday_market_state` looks like this:

```
  time            market_state 
 10:02:02          intraday 
 10:05:03          intraday
```

The input above (after some python code) becomes:

```
  time            market_state 
 5:00:00             open  
 7:30:00           continuous
 9:12:00           unscheduled
 10:02:02          intraday 
 11:00:33          closed
```

As mentioned the python code combines all rows with consecutive market_states. But now I want to replace the one tow of `intraday` with the two lines that I stored `store_intraday_market_state`.

Is there some code where I can do this replacing? *Using the `market_state` `intraday`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestand the question correctly, once you have extracted:

*store_intraday_market_state* into another dataframe, you can drop such rows from the original dataframe:

df = df[df['market_state'] != 'intraday']

and then do:

df = pandas.concat([df, store_intraday_market_state])

resulting dataframe should contain all the rows from original dataframe except the ones containing intraday and all rows from the stored dataframe with rows containing intraday.

edit: if you want it sorted, you can then do:

df.sort_values(by='time', ascending=True, inplace=True)

Comment: Yes this was what I was going for. Does it add the two rows to the bottom of the dataframe by default?

Comment: yes, by default it appends rows from the second frame to the first, in order they are passed to the concat function.